# Install PHP 5.3.X, PHP 5.4.x and PHP 5.5.x in the same environment using Puppet

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

Anyone already tried to install these three version using Puppet in Ubuntu?

I have a VM that is managed by Vagrant and I want to have these three version so I can specify which PHP version I should use based on the version of Drupal I am using.

Comment: Use separate VMs for this. There's no need to install three versions of PHP in the same VM and it's almost impossible to get right.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael. 
Do you already know https://puphpet.com/ ? It helps you create this 3 separate VMs fast&easy

Comment: yeah Im using that. I am just wondering if that's doable so I don't need to create other VM as my machine is not really fast. I am working on different versions of Drupal in parallel so the less VM running the better.

Comment: ah ok :) I'm using vagrant on ubuntu with lxc - much faster then virtualbox etc

Comment: Kevin...thanks man. Didnt realize that Vagrant could use LXC. Trying it now and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: As a side note, I'm currently looking into puphpet and am finding that it no longer supports PHP 5.3. However, the Vagrant cloud still has an Ubuntu Trusty box, and you get 5.3 if you install PHP with `apt-get install php5` on that box.